# You can't click an element after you replace it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have element with click event. On click I replace this element by another, but element class is same (event by class(jQuery)). But click doesn't work 2 time.

Comment: Please provide your code so we can help you figure out what the issue is.

Comment: The event handler is bound to the element, not the class, so replacing it also removes the event handler

Comment: Are you using `.on()` or `.click()`?

Comment: as @dustmouse, only way to help is if you show your code

Answer (score 1):

Bind the event on the parent node:

```
<div id="the_parent">
    <button>Replace me!</button>
</div>
```

```
$('#the_parent').on('click', 'button', function (ev) {
   // TODO: handle appropriately
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler:

> #### `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`
>
> #### selector
>
> Type: String
>
> A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is `null` or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

Comment: Technically that method uses event delegation. See that link for further explanations: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

You have to [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) the event to the new element which replaces the previous one.